# Needing advanced ID3 tag handling for specific situation

Tags: batch-file, mp3, rename, batch-rename, id3

My situation is probably quite rare and complex, so I'll explain it in detail.

Many years ago, I put together a hand-selected collection of MP3s, which ended up taking a month or so and is now at 8000 songs. All of these songs were manually ID3 tagged, which took me forever. Unfortunately, I had a strange tagging philosophy. For songs that featured multiple artists, I would put the features in the Artist field, rather than the Title field. Here's what I mean:

> What I have: OB O'Brien (ft. Drake) - 2 On/Thotful
>
> What every normal person has: OB O'Brien - 2 On/Thotful (ft. Drake)

Is there any software or script that handles ID3 tags that will let me perform an advanced renaming like this? Basically, I want to batch handle my MP3s so that if "(ft. *)" is found in the Artist field, it is removed and instead appended to the end of the Title field. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no tools that would do what you describe.  Hence, my approach would be to write a script to do this.  I've had success in the past with [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/).  It is both a command-line tool and has a python interface; so you can use whatever language you like.  I am always nervous with tools (or scripts) that change everything so maybe test it out very carefully first.  And perhaps even keep original copies of the changed songs for a while afterwards for paranoia sake.